# Is there any benefit to using an in-vm Channel vs short-circuiting to make local java object-object calls?

Tags: netty

BACKGROUND:
I'm in the process of prototyping a federated/distributed solution that is going to use Netty for the communication infrastructure.

I understand I am going to have to create some functionality around Netty to achieve what we need, but I want to understand what Netty provides so I don't re-invent the wheel.

GOAL:
I need to provide a general purpose communication dispatching layer that will automatically pick the appropriate communication channel based on the target endpoint being communicated with.

If the target is local, we want to communicate in-vm.  If it's remote, we plan to use our own binary format over websockets.  We'll know whether it's local or remote, so it's a matter of creating/picking the right Channel.

I expect each server instance will have a Channel cache/map of some sort.  This would include:

- 1 (in-vm) Channel
- 0+ (websocket) Channel(s): 1 for each server-server channel

QUESTION:
Given our goal, for local(in-vm) communication, should we:

- use LocalChannel?
- use EmbeddedChannel? - not sure what this is intended for
- short circuit the calls and communicate directly without using an official Channel?

Is there much of a performance difference using LocalChannel vs short-circuiting the local calls?  If we can eliminate encoding/decoding in the local case, that would be preferred.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have used Jetlang with Netty for in-vm messaging in the following [multi player game server](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server). You might want to look at the [UDP part of the code](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server/blob/master/jetserver/src/main/java/org/menacheri/jetserver/handlers/netty/UDPUpstreamHandler.java) to see how I do session lookup etc. This seems little bit similar to your usecase.
`EmbeddedChannel` is used for testing purposes. Please check out the test cases of jetserver to see example of it in use. It is not meant for mainstream use.
Not sure how you will do without using a channel so am unable to answer that piece.

Comment: Thanks Abe!  I see the JetLang is modeled after the Akka/Erlang actor/supervisor model, which has influenced some of my design ideas.  After posting, I found the 4.0 API docs described what Embedded was for.  Also, after digging into the unittest code, I've found some hands-on that shows LocalChannel use.  So, now it's time to experiment.